# Avoiding multiple "@media" when using Bootstrap 3 less mixins

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less, mixins

When using less mixins to build a Website with Bootstrap I do something like this:

```
#logo {
   .make-sm-column(3);
   .make-md-column(3);
   .make-lg-column(3);
}
#menu {
       .make-sm-column(5);
       .make-md-column(5);
       .make-lg-column(5);
    }
```

This looks very neat in the .less file but it does bloat up the compiled css a lot, isn't it?
Every class and id with such a mixin gets it's own set of media-queries:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
      #logo {
        float: left;
        width: 25%;
      }
    }
    @media (min-width: 992px) {
      #logo {
        float: left;
        width: 25%;
      }
    }
    @media (min-width: 1200px) {
      #logo {
        float: left;
        width: 25%;
      }
    }
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      #menu {
        float: left;
        width: 41.66666666666667%;
      }
    }
    @media (min-width: 992px) {
      #menu {
        float: left;
        width: 41.66666666666667%;
      }
    }
    @media (min-width: 1200px) {
      #menu {
        float: left;
        width: 41.66666666666667%;
      }
    }
```

This gets repeated for every class/id with the column-mixin. I think it would be more elegant and more effective to combine these definitions in 3 media-query blocks.

Is there a way I can do this (semi-)automatically.
I am using Windows and compiling with WinLess at the moment, but havent found such an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [`.make-xs-column` mixin](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.1.1/less/mixins.less#L654) in current Bootstrap version, it generates the same CSS without any media queries.

Comment: The .make-xs-column mixin doesn't add media queries, because bs3 is mobile first. But that's not my problem: I want media queries, because I want a responsive layout, but I want them concentrated in 3 blocks instead scattered around the css dozens/hundreds of times

Comment: But what is the point of having *exactly* the same code within a selector for each media query? Notice all three make function generate *absolutely identical* code regardless of min-width value (i.e. those media queries have no effect on `float` and `width` values so replacing these three `.make` calls with one `.make-xs` call will give you the same result w/o media bloating).

Comment: Either way there's nothing much you can do about that - this is just how those mixins are written (i.e. as soon as media query is generated by a mixin call (e.g. `.make-sm-column(3);`) you can't merge it with media queries generated by another mixin expansion (e.g. `.make-sm-column(5);`). Probably you could get it merged with some another post-processing tools (e.g. one of CSS minifiers) but I don't know if any is actually capable of that.

Comment: The other way around would be just to write your own `make-column` mixins that handle all this "the right way™", it's not too hard but that would mean that you'll have to review/update your code each time BS is updated.

Comment: ok, seven-phrases-max, you've convinced me.
I am going to use make-xs-column and create the media queries manually by hand

Comment: @seven-phases-max have a look at [gulp-combine-media-queries](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-combine-media-queries), there is also a [grunt version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-combine-media-queries)

Comment: @darronz Yes, I'm aware of media query merging tools. But the question (at least how it is written) was simply about making a column that works same way on either screen, thus it does not need any media queries at all.

Answer (score 1):

Little late, but if you note the min-width in those media queries, you don't need to make the medium and large columns if they're the same as the small. You only need to specify the medium and large columns if they're different than your small columns. This is all you need to do:

```
#logo {
   .make-sm-column(3);
}
#menu {
   .make-sm-column(5);
}
```

That will output the minimal amount of code to get your desired layout.